# is oauth2 only used when there is a third party authorization?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, passwords, authorization

I am reading about oauth2 now, and trying to understand its purpose. From all the resouces I read, it seems like oauth2 is only used when a webapp (say a game app) that has some users and the app wants to access a user's Facebook or Google data (some sort of data such as name or email, etc). This part is clear to me. However, things that remain unclear to me are the following:

1. For example: If I have a webapp, and I want the users of my webapp to log into the webapp with their login and passwords (just like how you do it with gmail) without using any third party. Does oauth2 also serve this type of authorization?
2. I have seen webapps, where they just let users sign up with IDs and passwords, then they salt the passwords and store the salts in the database. So when a user logs in later, they salt the password the user entered, and compare this salt to the salt in the database (created during the signup). If equal, then the user logged in. This does NOT seem like oath at all to me. So if this is not oauth, what standard is this? And are there any other standards for "direct login" like this?
3. Assume that I want to allow users to sign up and log in to my website, but let them log in via a third party (like Facebook or Google). This is just for authorization purposes and assume that my app has no plan to post on their facebook or request their facebook data except that I may want to use their facebook email as the user ID for my webapp. Does oauth2 serve this type of authorization?

Sorry for the naive questions, because I only read about oauth recently.

Answer (score 6):

1. For sign-up/login without 3rd-party, as Kevin pointed out, each programming/web framework usually comes with a popular library that once, it will generate all the sign-up/login pages, database tables, flow, etc., for you. The only thing you then do is call a method provided by the library that returns the current signed in user, in your backend code when you need to figure out who the user is.
2. Using [salted password scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) is NOT related to [OAuth 2.0](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6749.txt) at all as you pointed out. It is a widely used scheme for local authentication because it has many benefits but I will just highlight 2 here:

a. A password when transmitted from user to server for authentication over the Internet is not sent in cleartext but rather in hashed format. Thus even if it were eavesdropped, the password will not be divulged.

b. Since each password is salted, even 2 same passwords will not have the same hash because each have different salt. Thus even if a password hash was eavesdropped, it cannot be reused at another service that the user uses the same password because the other service expected a password hash generated with a different salt.

3. OAuth2 is all about Authorization (asking a user for permission to perform something on her behalf at another web service, e.g., ask a user for permission to access her email address registered on Facebook). Using it for Authentication can be insecure (for OAuth2 implicit flow). Why? The end result of OAuth2 is an access key associated with a permission, e.g., 'permission to access email address'. When you use the OAuth2 result (access key) for authentication, it means that you are making the assumption that 'permission to access email address' means the user successfully authenticated with Facebook, which she did, so it seems fine. However, imagine if another site also uses OAuth2 for authentication as you did; if it receives an access key with 'permission to access email address' it will assume that you have authenticated with Facebook so it will grant you access to the account belonging to the email address. You could actually use the access key you got from a user, and login as her in the other site, and vice versa.

To use OAuth2 for authentication, you need to use it with OpenID Connect (OIDC), because the end result of OAuth2-OIDC contains an id_token with the aud (audience) field identifying who the access key is for (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken), which prevents the access key from being reused where it is not intended. The full explanation with easy-to-understand diagrams is here: https://www.slideshare.net/KhorSoonHin/the-many-flavors-of-oauth/36?src=clipshare

Another very simple but perhaps unnerving to a security-conscious way to do use OAuth2 for login is to use the Resource Owner Password Credential, where your website acts as a middle-man between the user, and OAuth2 provider (Facebook).

1. Show 'Login with Facebook' button
2. When user clicks on button, prompt user for Facebook username/password
3. Use the username/password to login to Facebook to confirm authentication and get access token.

If you don't have to time to read in-depth about OAuth2, perhaps this side-by-side comparison of all the OAuth2 flow can help.

[image: Comparing flow diagrams for all four OAuth2 flow/grant types]

This is courtesy of https://blog.oauth.io/introduction-oauth2-flow-diagrams/

Answer (score 3):

1. You could use OAuth for local logins like this, but you don't have to. It might be easier, depending on available libraries, and it might make sense if you anticipate making your service available to third-parties in the future. For many sites, though, using OAuth for local logins would be overkill.
2. Standards are most useful when different actors need to speak a common language so they can interoperate. For local logins you don't need a standard because you're not interacting with any third parties. Many web frameworks include their own variation on the same basic flow.
3. I think you're asking whether OAuth makes sense for *authentication* (establishing identity) when you don't actually need any *authorization* (permission to access third-party resources). It can indeed be used that way, but lots of people will warn against it since it wasn't designed for that and has some security weaknesses in that context. See, for example, [Common pitfalls for authentication using OAuth](https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/#common-pitfalls).

Comment: Kevin, thanks. Are there any well-known existing frameworks/libs for local logins that you know of? Or nothing like that exists and every website has to implement their own? I was reading about JWT (jason web token) lately and still trying to figure out if that is something used for local login. JWT is more like a standard than a framework though.

Comment: @Simo: Most web framework will include some sort of authentication implementation, and many will also support third-party packages adding additional functionality. Just to take the example I'm most familiar with, Django (the Python web framework) has its own [authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/), and there are third-party projects adding [OAuth](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [integrated social logins](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), etc.